# Upgrading from tensorflow 1.x to 2.0

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, python-3.6

I am new to tensorflow.
Have tried this simple example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
sess = tf.Session()
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
z = x + y
print(sess.run(z, feed_dict={x: 3.0, y: 4.5}))
```

and got some warnings `The name tf.Session is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.Session instead.` and the right answer - `7.5`

After reading [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/guide/migration_guide#1_replace_v1sessionrun_calls), I understand that the warnings are due to upgrading from tf 1.x to 2.0, the steps described are "simple" but they don't give any example....

I have tried:

```
@tf.function
def f1(x1, y1):
    return tf.math.add(x1, y1)


print(f1(tf.constant(3.0), tf.constant(4.5)))
```

1. Is my code correct (in the sense defined in the link)?
2. **Now, I am getting `Tensor("PartitionedCall:0", shape=(), dtype=float32)` as output, how can I get the actual value?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You code is indeed correct. The warning that you get indicates that as from Tensorflow 2.0, `tf.Session()` won't exist in the API. Therefore, if you want you code to be compatible with Tensorflow 2.0, you should use `tf.compat.v1.Session` instead. So, just change this line:

```
sess = tf.Session()
```

To:

```
sess = tf.compat.v1.Session()
```

Then, even if you update Tensorflow from 1.xx to 2.xx, your code would execute in the same way. As for the code in Tensorflow 2.0:

```
@tf.function
def f1(x1, y1):
    return tf.math.add(x1, y1)

print(f1(tf.constant(3.0), tf.constant(4.5)))
```

it is fine if you run it in Tensorflow 2.0. If you want to run the same code, without installing Tensorflow 2.0, you can do the following:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.enable_eager_execution()

@tf.function
def f1(x1, y1):
    return tf.math.add(x1, y1)

print(f1(tf.constant(3.0), tf.constant(4.5)).numpy())
```

The reason for this is because the default way of executing Tensorflow operations starting from Tensorflow 2.0 is in eager mode. The way of activating eager mode in Tensorflow 1.xx, is to enable it right after the import of Tensorflow, as I am doing it in the example above.

Comment: isn't this method disables som of tf 2.0 features (which I don't know at all...)?

Comment: The default way of running operations in Tensorflow 2.0 is in eager mode. However, you can still do it in the current way.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct as per Tensorflow 2.0. Tensorflow 2.0 is even more tightly bonded with numpy so if you want to get the result of the operation, you could use the `numpy()` method:

```
print(f1(tf.constant(3.0), tf.constant(4.5)).numpy())
```

Comment: Are you sure? have just tried `print(f1(tf.constant(3.0), tf.constant(4.5)).numpy())` and got `AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'`

Comment: @BennyK [yep](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1dBTyfUpceU_L8-PYmUffHQHOrVjWCq-O) :)

Comment: Yes, as gorjan pointed in his answer for tf 1.x I should add `tf.enable_eager_execution()` to get it work

Comment: For tf 1, yes, you do, in tensorflow 2, eager execution is on by default.

Comment: Makes sense. what I don't understand is why I got this warning in the first place if I am using tf 1.x?

Comment: I have a suspicion you are on 1.x to be honest. Check `tf.__version__`.

Comment: It seems so, I got `1.14.0`, so why did I get the `The name tf.Session is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.Session instead` warning???

Comment: Good question. I really can't say. Maybe using different interpreters/virtualenvs or something and you got mixed up which one you're currently using or you managed to mash 1 and 2 together somehow. I say create a new virtualenv and keep them isolated.

Comment: Sorry for jumping in the discussion. Deprecated means that the thing for which you got the warning will be excluded from future versions. Because you are running TF 1.14, and `tf.Session` will be excluded in TF 2.0, the warning tells you to change it to `tf.compat.v1.Session` since `tf.compat.v1.Session` will remain in the TF 2.0 API.

Comment: Ah, true, @gorjan is correct, sorry somehow my brain didn't register it's a warning and kept thinking you got an exception. Nice catch :)